# Iterate by two using a for loop in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm sorry for something that is a very dumb question. I'm a C programmer so I'm not that used to Python.

How would you write the equivalent for loop into python:

```
int x;

for(x = 0; x < 10; x+=2) <----- I don't know how to iterate by two in python.

for x in range(10):
```

How would I change the python code to make it do 0, 2, 4, 6, 8?

Python 2.7 (if that matters)

Comment: RT(fine)M http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for x in range(0, 10, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) for range.  You need to supply it a "step."

> range(start, stop[, step])
>
> This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is most often used in for loops. The arguments must
>   be plain integers. If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1.
>   If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form
>   returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 *
>   step, ...]. If step is positive, the last element is the largest start
>   + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero
>   (or else ValueError is raised).

So, use `for i in range(0,10,2)`.

Also, unless you explicitly need the `list` (you don't), consider using `xrange` in lieu of `range` in python 2.x.